# Lumen 5.4.x wrong table name

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-artisan

I´ve created a table by using artisan

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('log', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('priority');
        $table->string('level');
        $table->string('content');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

This worked perfectly, the table is existing.

After this I wanted to make an API call to get all (none are existing, I know) entrys via a GET request on `api/v1/log` which results in HTTP 500 error.

In lumens log (`storage/logs/lumen.log`) I can find the following:

`[2017-06-21 10:20:28] lumen.ERROR: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'serviceAPI.logs' doesn't exist in [...]`

can anyone tell me why the API trys to open `logs` instead of `log`?

**UPDATE:** the Log model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Log extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['priority', 'level', 'content'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database table name needs to be change to `log` instead of `logs`

You can change the table name from logs model

```
protected $table = 'log';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

Comment: As described in alle tutorials I´ve seen so far there is no name defined in the model, so I can´t change/rename anything in the model regarding the table name (I´ve added the model in the OP).

Comment: Did you try like this

class Log extends Model
{  
protected $table = 'log';
protected $fillable = ['priority', 'level', 'content'];
}
?>

Comment: This did work. At this point my question would still be "why did lumen used 'logs' before if it wasn´t configured anywhere?"